# Ternary Put Operator in cpp possible?

Tags: c++, stream, operator-keyword, put, ternary

I was thinking about implementing a ternary put operator in cpp similar to "<<":

```
mystream <<< param2 param3;
```

Is this possible? Does it already exist? One remark: I remember having seen this:

```
out <<STDERR param
```

Wouldnt this already be a ternary operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send C++ output to the stderr stream, use `cerr << var1 << var2` or `clog << 1 << 2`.

There is exactly one ternary operator in C++, `?:`, and it cannot be overloaded.

`<<<` is a binary operator in all languages where I've seen it. C++ does not have it; such a character sequence would be parsed as `<< <` which is nonsense as neither can be used as a unary operator.

Finally, the second and third "operands" there are separated only by whitespace. C++ has no grammar productions including `expression expression`; that would lead to serious ambiguities.

---

The chaining behavior as in `cerr << var1 << var2` is achieved by overloads of the form

```
std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream &, my_class const & );
```

The `ostream &` return type allows the result of the first call `cerr << var1` to be used as the left-hand operand to `<< var2`.

Comment: Thanks, good answer too. I was looking to implement a manipulator that does not have to be separated by "<<"

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't make up new operators. You may only use the existing ones, and `<<<` is not among them.

```
out <<STDERR param
```

this can mean anything, both can be macros or literals.

Comment: ok so the only way would be to overload "<<" to handle a struct or class that contains the "param1" and "param2"... Thanks!

Comment: @BM yep, guess so. Or that's at least one of the options.